# Using ifstream to retrieve full string within quotes

Tags: c++, string, file-io

I am trying to create a function that loads in a set of data that represents a menu.  The layout of the file looks like this:

DS Test Menu

6

MENU "Start" "play.mnu"

MENU "Options" "opt.mnu"

MENU "Help" "help.mnu"

OPTION "Data Structures Project 1B"

OPTION "Full Sail"

OPTION "Game Design and Development"

The first line is the title of the menu, the second line is the number of menu items.
Each line after is an item on that menu. My problem comes when extracting the name of each menu item which is in quotes.

Here is what I have tried:

```
ifstream fin;
fin.open(filepath.c_str(), ios_base::in);

if (fin.is_open())
{
    getline(fin, this->title);

    int numMenuItems;
    fin >> numMenuItems;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < numMenuItems; i++)
    {
        menuItem temp;
        string menutitle;
        fin >> menutitle;
        if (menutitle == "MENU")
        {
            string name, filepath;
            fin >> name;
            fin >> filepath;
            name = name.substr(1, name.length() - 2);
            filepath = filepath.substr(1, filepath.length() - 2);
            temp.is_subMenu = true;
            temp.name = name;
            temp.subMenuPath = filepath;
        }
        else
        {
            string name;
            fin >> name;
            name = name.substr(1, name.length() - 2);
            temp.is_subMenu = false;
            temp.name = name;
        }

    }
}
```

This works well for the first 3 menu items, my problem arises when the name of the menu item in the quotes is several words long. I know this is because using the extraction operator only extracts until the first whitespace. I also have to use the string substr method in order to lose the quotes.

I'm not sure of a better way to extract the data and ignore the quotes and I cannot change the format that the data is stored in.

What would be the best way of going about extracting this information?

Comment: Not a direct solution, but if you have control over the file format you should consider using distinct separators like tabs.

Comment: Should have included this. I do not have control over file format. I have to this specific format.

Comment: After reading the command `MENU` or `OPTION`, you probably want to use `getline` to grab the remainder of the line ignoring spaces.  You can even tell `getline` to read until the next quote.

Comment: you could read the whole line using ```getline``` and then read char by char.

Comment: @BenVoigt I like this idea, however is there a way to read until the second quote?

Comment: Read until a quote, twice?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @BenVoigt I was able to get it working.

```
if (fin.is_open())
{
    getline(fin, this->title);

    int numMenuItems;
    fin >> numMenuItems;



    for (int i = 0; i < numMenuItems; i++)
    {
        menuItem temp;
        string tempshit;
        fin >> tempshit;
        if (tempshit == "MENU")
        {
            string name, filepath, temp2;
            getline(fin, temp2, '"');
            getline(fin, name, '"');
            getline(fin, temp2, '"');
            getline(fin, filepath, '"');
            temp.is_subMenu = true;
            temp.name = name;
            temp.subMenuPath = filepath;
        }
        else
        {
            string name, temp2;
            getline(fin, temp2, '"');
            getline(fin, name, '"');
            temp.is_subMenu = false;
            temp.name = name;
        }


    }
}
```